# Loading cursor bug when using pyside on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

I have python 3.3 + PySide 1.1.2 on my Windows XP. The code which is enough for the bug to show up:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

wid = QtGui.QWidget()
wid.resize(250, 150)
wid.setWindowTitle('Simple')
wid.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So what is the bug? When I save it as "test.py" everything runs great, but there is unwanted console window. So I save it as "test.pyw" to run using pythonw (so there is no console window). The problem is that for like 15 sec no matter what I do, the cursor is the loading cursor. [IMAGE WHICH SHOWS IT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04PqO.jpg)

After about 15 sec the cursor returns back to normal. It can't be app loading because 1) it's very small 2) running it with python instead of pythonw doesn't show the loading cursor even for a while.

Is it a known bug? How can I fix it? It's very annoying, I wanted to create few simple GUI tools with pyside, but for end user such behaviour isn't good looking and I definetely don't want it. On linux there is no loading cursor too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in python windows launcher in 3.3. I reported it and it got fixed.